# How to add multiple listViews to a single listView?

Tags: android, listview

I have been facing a problem since 40days . i didn't get a solution . Here am describing  my problem

In a single list i need different types of lists  . for example three list with types 
List A , ListB , List C. i mean in a same list view i  have three different types of views.
List A contain textView and Button . List B and List C are diffenrt types . My problem ,

1. How to display a list with below criteria .
2. when ever i click  on button(RowA) i need to update list of List B.

In a ListView
(ListView 1)

1. List item  A
2. List item A
3. List item A

(ListView 2)
 4.  **Header**
 5. List item B
 6. List item B
 7. List item B
 8. **Header**
 9. List item C
 10. List item C
 11. List item C

Can any one sort out this problem ? Gimme a solution .

Thanking you,
Srinivas

Comment: really, i didn't get your question.. some snippet will clear what you doin'..can you please post it

Comment: I need different listviews in a single listView .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below link should help you.
http://umakantpatil.com/posts/android-listview-with-separate-headers-and-images-loading-from-remote-server

Its just uses header for separating the list. You can anyways remove those headers.

Comment: Thank you .. thank u . i solved to some extent . See cani upodate individual list dynamically

Comment: You can anytime update individual list. As each list is an separate adapter. And each adapter can be customized

Answer (score 0):

Ok What i prefer you here is to use a [custom adapter](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/) by  `extends BaseAdapter` .

Add all the component in your list view xml.

Then overriding `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`
First arg, position we will get which row, so you can make the the needed component visible and other gone by setting its visibility